# Inconsistent behaviour between dict.values() and dict.keys() equality in Python 3.x and Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have found that comparing the results of the `keys()` and `values()` methods of the `dict` built-in to themselves results in inconsistent results:

```
instance = {'one': 1}

instance.values() == instance.values() # Returns False
instance.keys() == instance.keys()     # Returns True
```

Running the above code in Python 2.7 will return True for both calls, leading me to believe that there is some implementation detail in Python 3's `dict_values` that causes this strange behaviour.

Is there a reason for this behaviour or have i stumbled upon some obscure bug?

Comment: This seems to be interesting as I just checked `id` of two values and they are same as well still `==` is returning `False`. I believe one has to dig a bit more in the source code to find the reason for it.

Comment: Don't know the answer, but it can be simplified to `d.values() == d.values()` is false.

Comment: Good catch, I'll edit my question to be more general.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

The short answer: `class dict_values` doesn't have a `__eq__` method implemented, but `class dict_keys` does:

```
>>> d.values().__eq__(d.values())
NotImplemented
>>> d.keys().__eq__(d.keys())
True
```

Therefore, the `d.values()`'s `==` comparison evaluates to `False`.

The longer answer of *why* it wasn't implemented is a different one and can be seen with a little more digging on [the documentation of dict-view objects](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dictionary-view-objects).  This part seems especially relevant (emphasis mine):

> **Keys views are set-like since their entries are unique and hashable**.
> If all values are hashable, so that (key, value) pairs are unique and
> hashable, then the items view is also set-like. (Values views are not
> treated as set-like since the entries are generally not unique.) For
> set-like views, all of the operations defined for the abstract base
> class `collections.abc.Set` are available **(for example, `==`, `<`, or `^`)**.

Since keys must be unique, it makes sense that they are set-like and are supported with the class operations of `collections.Set`.  Values are not set-like due to non-uniqueness.

In Python 2.7, `d.keys()` and `d.values()` *both* return a [`list` per the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items), so you'll get ordinary list comparison if you try `==`.  Of course, since the lists aren't guaranteed to be in any particular order, the comparison doesn't actually do what you want, but you can perform the comparison if you really want to:

```
x = {0: 'x', 16: 'x'}
y = {16: 'x', 0: 'x'}

# prints False twice - you'd get True on Python 3.
print x.keys() == y.keys()
print x.items() == y.items()
```

If you used `viewkeys` and `viewvalues` [as mentioned in the documentation of dict-view objects in Python2.7](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dictionary-view-objects), then you can expect similar behaviour to Python 3:

```
# Python 2.7
from collections import Set
# in Python 3.x this would be from collections.abc import Set

d = {"one": 1}

print isinstance(d.viewkeys(), Set)
# True

print isinstance(d.viewvalues(), Set)
# False

print d.viewkeys() == d.viewkeys()
# True

print d.viewvalues() == d.viewvalues()
# False
```

Comment: I suppose it's possible that on Python 2 two different dict objects with the same keys might return them in a different order, whereas the documentation implies that on Python 3 the order of keys is ignored during comparisons.