# Equivalence of view objects of Python dict

Tags: python, dictionary, equality

View objects for Python `dict` compare differently than I would expect:

```py
a = {0 : 'a', 1 : 'b'}
b = {1 : 'b', 0 : 'a'}

print(a == b) # True
print(a.keys() == b.keys()) # True
print(a.values() == b.values()) # False
print(a.items() == b.items()) # True
```

Is there any particular reason why for `dict.values()` this is `False`?

In fact, in the case of same `dict`s (not even the copy), it is also `False`:

```py
a = {0 : 'a', 1 : 'b'}
print(a.values() == a.values()) # False
```

What does the equality of this view object mean then?

Comment: See [Inconsistent behaviour between dict.values() and dict.keys() equality in Python 3.x and Python 2.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55026840/inconsistent-behaviour-between-dict-values-and-dict-keys-equality-in-python).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`keys` and `items` views are set-like (or mostly set-like for `items` views with non-hashable values) - they behave like `set` objects in many ways, and particularly, it's easy to perform `in` tests on such views. That lets those views support an efficient `==` operation based on whether the two views contain the same elements.

For `values` views, there's no good way to implement such an `==` operation, so `values` views *don't* implement anything fancy for `==`. They just inherit the default `__eq__` implementation from `object`, so two `values` views will only be considered equal if they're the same object. Even for two views of the same dict, you'll only get `True` if they're actually the same view object:

```
In [2]: x = {}

In [3]: x.values() == x.values()
Out[3]: False

In [4]: v = x.values()

In [5]: v == v
Out[5]: True
```

Comment: thanks for the answer!
   "there's no good way to implement such an == operation..." ->
What is wrong with: `def __eq__(self, other): return all(i == j for i, j in zip(self, other))`?

Comment: @tungli That requires the elements of the two dictionaries to be in the same order.

Comment: @tungli: That brings element order into the comparison, resulting in cases where equal dicts have unequal values views. It's inconsistent with dict comparison and with how all the other view comparisons work. (Also, you forgot to check `len` first.)

Comment: Also, these design decisions were made before dicts became order-preserving.

Comment: Not sure that matters, since none of these operators care about order. Perhaps the best way to implement values equality would be something like `Collections.counter(self) == Collections.counter(other)`

Comment: Counter requires hashable elements.

Answer (score 2):

Dictionary view classes implement their own equality method. The documentation of [`dict.values()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.values) specifically says:

> An equality comparison between one `dict.values()` view and another will always return False. This also applies when comparing `dict.values()` to itself

For `dict.keys()` and `dict.items()`, the documentation of [dictionary views](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict-views) says:

> Keys views are set-like since their entries are unique and hashable. If all values are hashable, so that `(key, value)` pairs are unique and hashable, then the items view is also set-like. (Values views are not treated as set-like since the entries are generally not unique.) For set-like views, all of the operations defined for the abstract base class `collections.abc.Set` are available (for example, `==`, `<`, or `^`).

Comment: thanks! I missed that. Any insight on why it has to return False though? It seems kind of a waste of a good operator...

Comment: To avoid having to do something expensive like sort the list of all values in order to compare them.

Comment: `keys` and `items` can be treated like sets because the keys are guaranteed to be unique and hashable. But values can have duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

`dict` is un-ordered, meaning that as long as all keys in `a` exist in `b` and all keys in `b` exist in `a` and all values for those keys are equal, the two sets are equal.

If you're instead trying to check if `a` and `b` are the same *instance*, then you would use `is`.

```
>>> a = {0 : 'a', 1 : 'b'}
>>> b = {1 : 'b', 0 : 'a'}

>>> a is b
False

>>> a = {0 : 'a', 1 : 'b'}
>>> b = a

>>> a is b
True
```

As for the question about why `a.values() == b.values()` returns `False`, this is a choice made in the Python language. A quote taken from the Python docs:

> An equality comparison between one dict.values() view and another will
> always return False. This also applies when comparing dict.values() to
> itself:
>
> ```
> >>> d = {'a': 1}
> >>> d.values() == d.values()
> False
> ```

Comment: That doesn't explain why `keys()` and `items()` objects are equal, but `values()` objects are not equal

Comment: as @Barmar says, it is missing the point. I could understand if e.g. `a.values() is a.values()` returned `False`, but with `==` it is weird.

Comment: also, `dict` is now insertion-ordered [(since 3.7)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict)

Comment: I updated the answer to answer that question.

Comment: That doc section isn't quite right - it is possible for `==` on `values` views to return `True`, but only if you're comparing the same view object to itself. Calling `values` twice returns two different view objects, so you get `False` for `d.values() == d.values()`.

Comment: The docs need more clarity there, I agree, as they seem to contradict themselves. It states that a new view is returned with each call, and as such, results in a comparison between two different views, which should return `False`. No idea why comparing it to itself returns `True` though.