# dict.keys() equality, order irrelevant

Tags: python

Why do I get `True` why comparing `dict.keys()` when the keys are in different orders?  I'm on windows cpython 3.10, which preserves insertion order since 3.6+, but I wonder if this result holds for earlier versions.

```
d1 = {1:2, 2:3, 3:4}
d2 = {3:5, 2:6, 1:7}

print(d1.keys() == d2.keys()) # True
print(list(d1.keys()) == list(d2.keys())) # False
```

Comment: `keys()` doesn't return a list, it returns a `dict_keys` object. These perform order-independent equality, for consistency with comparing dictionaries.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Equivalence of view objects of Python dict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67097925/equivalence-of-view-objects-of-python-dict)

Comment: That question is aimed at the difference between dict.keys() and dict.values(), although it does mention the set-like quality of the views.  I think the difference is focus is significant, but can see your point of view.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The docs for [Dictionary view objects](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dictionary-view-objects) explain as follows:

> Keys views are set-like since their entries are unique and hashable. If all values are hashable, so that (key, value) pairs are unique and hashable, then the items view is also set-like. (Values views are not treated as set-like since the entries are generally not unique.) For set-like views, all of the operations defined for the abstract base class collections.abc.Set are available (for example, ==, <, or ^).

So `==` will work just as if `dict.keys()` were a set.

Comment: Aha!  That was the documentation I was missing.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Dict keys may be retrieved in insertion order but its still a set, and sets should compare regardless of order. In fact, all set comparison operations work (and return python `set` when appropriate). It would be strange if `d1 | d2` operated differently depending on insertion order. Equality is the same.

Comment: It's not a set, it's a special `dict_keys` type.

Comment: @Barmar, right - its a set (as a generic term) but not a python `set`.

Comment: Although it remembers the insertion order if you iterate through it.

Comment: @Barmar, right - but all of the set operations work and in fact return you a python `set`.